# Microsoft Edge Configuration Export

Tags: configuration

Is there a way to export all the Microsoft Edge configuration to a file? Registry tree? Folder?

One thing that annoys me is the lost of Edge's configuration. I like some particular configuration I've done. Every time there is an update o Edge, it resets the whole configuration and I have to reconfigure it all again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered configuring a local or domain GPO for Edge and leaving that for persistence or exporting for future use?

[Available policies for Microsoft Edge](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/microsoft-edge/available-policies)

Alternatively, if you're looking for the setup for the Favorites and Favorites bar, these can be exported by HTML or via LocalAppData: [see here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7256-microsoft-edge-favorites-backup-restore-windows-10-a.html)